# How can I create a download link in a joomla article?

Tags: joomla, download, joomla2.5

I want to create a download link for a PDF file in a Joomla (version 2.5) article. For example, it will be written that please click here to download this file... I already uploaded the file to the media manager and its location is already set. I also already tried to create a link in the article for it. When I click the link, I get an error message of my hosting company. What should I do?
Thank you.

Comment: And what might the error message be?

Comment: I cannot re-generate it because I already fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I fixed it. Inside the edit/insert link button (in article page's editor), there is link url field and I type the url as /images/pdf/documentName.pdf and now when I click the link, the pdf document is opened in pdf view format and it is downloadable by default.